# How do I use filtered_stream with rtweets package?

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet, tweetr

I am using the latest `rtweet` package, and I’m getting stuck on the use of the filtered_stream function. I have been able to use other functions in the `rtweet` package just fine (`search_tweet`, `get_timeline`) but I’m missing something with `filtered_stream`.

Every time I run the filtered_stream it returns the message:

> “No matching tweets with streaming rules were found in the time
> provided.”

I thought this might mean that there were simply no tweets found, but this error message appears immediately after running the code even if I set the timeout to 120 seconds. Here is my code:

```
chat_rule <- stream_add_rule(list(value = "#chatgpt", tag = "chatgpt"))

chatgpt_stream <- filtered_stream(timeout = 120, filename = "chatgpt.json", parse = FALSE)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, due to removal of most of the functionality in the free tier of the Twitter API means rtweet no longer works (as far as I can tell). The "Final" section of this blog post by the current maintainer https://llrs.dev/post/2023/03/20/rtweet-starts-using-api-v2/ says that the party is over... which sucks.

Comment: Bummer. Thanks for posting the link.